# Updating database values through an Object list

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql

I made my program for a hypothetical restaurant (Diploma final project). I want a way to change inventory values based on the number of orders, e.g. if there are four orders, reduce four times as much from the inventory.

My proposed algorithm: User will input what items are needed and how much of it, and this data will be stored in an Object List (I've included the code below). At `button_Click`, a loop will run with an update statement. Before I go on, here's the List's code:

```
        public class Items
        {
            public string Types { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }

        List<Items> list = new List<Items>();

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Items co = new Items();
            co.Types = textBox3.Text;
            co.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            list.Add(co);
            var bindingList = new BindingList<Items>(list);   
            var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);            
            dataGridView2.DataSource = source;
        }
```

The Inventory Table has two columns: Types and Amount.

`Types` in the list will be the primary keys. `Amount` in the list will be the inventory's values. I want to use the update statement in the loop to change the values in the table based on `Amount` where primary key = `Types`.

I think I included everything. Please tell me if this question is missing any details.

Comment: You know how to execute an `UPDATE` query to database from C#?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya You mean this, right? `UPDATE table SET column=value WHERE primarykey=value`

Comment: Did you try use this in your current case to update first item in the list? what's the issue you are facing there?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Inexperience. What would the code look like if I told the loop to access each item in the list until there were no other items?

Comment: You need to learn about looping in C#. such as [for loop](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/for-loop) and [foreach loop](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/foreach-loop). If you can write code to update the first item which is `items[0]` you need to apply learning of loop to execute for all the items in the list.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya So, knowing how to execute a foreach loop and how to update a table is enough for my purpose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218342/discussion-between-zaid-hussain-and-chetan-ranpariya).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string sql = "select * from Test where Type='" + item.Types + "'";
                    com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    amount = int.Parse(dr["Amount"].ToString());
                    amount -= item.Amount;
                    dr.Close();

                    string upd = "update Test set Amount='" + amount + "' where Type='" + item.Types + "'";
                    com = new SqlCommand(upd, con);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    refresh_gridview();
                }
```

`refresh_gridview()` is a public method I made to refresh the dataGridView.
`Test` is my test dbo.Table